# Sending UDP packet in Linux Kernel

Tags: sockets, udp, linux-kernel

For a project, I'm trying to send UDP packets from Linux kernel-space. I'm currently 'hard-coding' my code into the kernel (which I appreciate isn't the best/neatest way) but I'm trying to get a simple test to work (sending "TEST"). It should be mentioned I'm a newbie to kernel hacking - I'm not that clued up on many principles and techniques!

Every time my code gets run the system hangs and I have to reboot - no mouse/keyboard response and the scroll and caps lock key lights flash together - I'm not sure what this means, but I'm assuming it's a kernel panic?

The repeat_send code is unnecessary for this test code, yet when it's working I want to send large messages that may require multiple 'send's - I'm not sure that if could be a cause of my issues?

N.B. This code is being inserted into neighbour.c of linux-source/net/core/ origin, hence the use of NEIGH_PRINTK1, it's just a macro wrapper round printk.

I'm really banging my head against a brick wall here, I can't spot anything obvious, can anyone point me in the right direction (or spot that blindingly obvious error!)?

Here's what I have so far:

```
void mymethod()
{
    struct socket sock;
    struct sockaddr_in addr_in;
    int ret_val;
    unsigned short port = htons(2048);
    unsigned int host = in_aton("192.168.1.254");
    unsigned int length = 5;
    char *buf = "TEST\0";
    struct msghdr msg;
    struct iovec iov;
    int len = 0, written = 0, left = length;
    mm_segment_t oldmm;

    NEIGH_PRINTK1("forwarding sk_buff at: %p.\n", skb);

    if ((ret_val = sock_create(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP, &sock)) < 0) {
        NEIGH_PRINTK1("Error during creation of socket; terminating. code: %d\n", ret_val);
        return;
    }

    memset(&addr_in, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    addr_in.sin_family=AF_INET;
    addr_in.sin_port = port;
    addr_in.sin_addr.s_addr = host;

    if((ret_val = sock.ops->bind(&sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr_in, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))) < 0) {
    NEIGH_PRINTK1("Error trying to bind socket. code: %d\n", ret_val);
    goto close;
    }

    memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(struct msghdr));
    msg.msg_flags = 0;
    msg.msg_name = &addr_in;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    msg.msg_iov = &iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
    msg.msg_control = NULL;
    msg.msg_controllen = 0;

repeat_send:
    msg.msg_iov->iov_len = left;
    msg.msg_iov->iov_base = (char *)buf + written;

    oldmm = get_fs(); 
    set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
    len = sock_sendmsg(&sock, &msg, left);
    set_fs(oldmm);

    if (len == -ERESTARTSYS)
        goto repeat_send;
    if (len > 0) {
        written += len;
        left -= len;
        if (left)
            goto repeat_send;
    }

close:
    sock_release(&sock);
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated, thanks!

Comment: After experimenting using similar code in a LKM, I was able to ascertain that the issue was being caused by trying to bind my socket to a remote ip! I should have been using connect instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find it easier to use the [netpoll API](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.31/include/linux/netpoll.h) for UDP. Take a look at [netconsole](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.31/drivers/net/netconsole.c) for an example of how it's used. The APIs you're using are more intended for userspace (you should never have to play with segment descriptors to send network data!)

Comment: That looks promising from a cursory glance. Thanks, I'll check it out properly, in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

Run your code when you're in a text mode console (i.e. press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to go to the text console). This way a kernel panic will print out the stack trace and any extra information about what went wrong.

If that doesn't help you, update your question with the stack trace.

Comment: Good tip, I certainly got the stack trace, but it quickly scrolled out of view (I can only see the last ~25 rows). Any way of storing/piping the output somewhere handy?

Comment: You can use a serial console, netconsole, or possibly kexec crash dumping.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a Linux Kernel developer, but can you throw some printk's in there and watch dmesg before it goes down?  Or have you thought about hooking up with a kernel debugger?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to put all variables outside mymethod() function and make them static. Remember, that the size of kernel stack is limited do 8KiB, so to much of/too big local variables may cause stack overflow and system hangup.